# @EnableResourceServer @EnableAuthorizationServer are deprecated?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am writing a simple application to test Oauth. But i see that both the annotations @EnableResourceServer @EnableAuthorizationServer were deprecated!

I don't find an alternative way to deal with it and I don't find any info anywhere.

What is the latest way to configure resource server and Auth server?

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the announcement of deprecating spring-security-oauth in [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update) and see the migration guide provided by spring security [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: OAuth2.0 resource server is now part of spring-security core. Unfortunately they do not have a replacement for EnableAuthorizationServer. I am following this GUIDE (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Answer (score 9):

As previous comments suggest this was originally dropped, but has recently been resurrected as https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server

See the news post [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server).

Answer (score 3):

From

https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

> In 2019, there are plenty of both commercial and open-source authorization servers available. Thus, the Spring Security team has decided to no longer provide support for authorization servers.
>
> UPDATE: We’d like to thank everyone for your feedback on the decision to not support Authorization Server. Due to this feedback and some internal discussions, we are taking another look at this decision. We’ll notify the community on any progress.

Basically spring drop support for auth servers since there is a lot of good service already working,not need to reinvent the whel. But they are rethinking it, I imagine it is to give more scope to sprig framework